# How should I adjust oven temperature/time to have two dishes ready at the same time?

Tags: baking, cooking-time

I want to cook two vegetable dishes at one time for a dinner party.

- The first, a vegetable loaf, has to be cooked at 325° F for 1 hour
- The other, a casserole, requires 350° F for 30 min.

How can I adjust temperatures or time to have these two ready at one time?

Comment: Does the casserole possibly need to be cooled for longer before being served, too?

Answer (score 6):

25ºF isn't such a big difference, so I'd just split the temperature in the middle: 335-340F.

Instead of 60', aim at 50' and check for doneness by sticking a pin in the loaf. If it comes out clean, it's done.

I'd leave the casserole at 30' and then check. If it's done, it's done. If not, you can keep the oven going some time more.

Answer (score 2):

Place the Vegetable Loaf into the oven set to **325 F**

- After **20 minutes** increase the heat up to **340 F**
- After **7 minutes** place also the Casserole into the oven, and
- After **31 minutes** both of them will be ready

So mathematically both of them will be ready in 58 minutes BUT practically it is wiser to follow the recommendation of `BaffledCook`. :)))

Comment: Is there a formula you followed for that?

Answer (score 1):

Place the vegetable loaf in 325° oven for 20 minutes. Then add the casserole beside your vegetable loaf in the 325° oven for 20 minutes. Then raise the oven temperature to 340° for another 20 minutes. You might want to check both dishes 5 to 10 minutes after raising the oven temperature to see if either one or both are done. If only one is finished cooking, remove it from oven and place it on top of stove to keep hot while your other dish finishes cooking.